# Angular validator limit number to first model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to create a custom validator that checks if the newly input number is greater or equal to the first value it has from the model bound to the input field, but I can't figure out what properties to use in the validator to do this. Currently I have an attribute `minvalue="{{data.mileage}}"` on my input field. The validator looks like this:

```
var minvalue = function (){ 
       return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
              var minval = attr.minvalue;

              ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                 var valid = !isNaN(parseFloat(minval));
                 console.log(minval);
                 if(valid){
                    valid = (value >= minval);
                    console.log(value);
                    console.log(minval);
                    ngModel.$setValidity('minvalue', valid);
                 }               
              });
          }
       };
    };
```

But I can't even get the correct value, it's always blank. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Your example has a parser, not a validator. What exactly do you mean by '_the first value it has from the model bound to the input field_'? The initial value?

Comment: @zeroflagL The initial value yes. The input field is bound to a model that has a value and the field should be invalid for any input lower than this number.